# Ui-router - difference between {slug} and :slug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use ui-router in my project, I saw both in documentation:

```
.state('app.restaurants.index', {
      url: '/{slug}',
      controller: 'listRestaurantsController',
      templateUrl: '/app/user/views/restaurants/list.html'
})
```

and

```
.state('app.restaurants.index', {
       url: '/:slug',
       controller: 'listRestaurantsController',
       templateUrl: '/app/user/views/restaurants/list.html'
})
```

What's the difference between `:slug` and `{slug}`?
I need to use optional parameter in url, what's your suggestion about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe both are the same, its just with "/{}" format you can define the type of the parameter that's gonna be passed.

like `url: '/{slug:int}'` here slug is type of int and uirouter will type check the parameter for you.

feel free to correct me,if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

They're both the same and serve the same purpose.

As the documentation says:

> Path parameters are defined using curly brace placeholders
>   (/somepath/{param}) or colon placeholders (/somePath/:param).

Reference: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/url.urlmatcher.html

Benefit of curly using braces is that you can add regex in it too, like this:

> A parameter RegExp may be defined for a param after a colon
>   (/somePath/{param:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}) in a curly brace placeholder. The
>   regexp must match for the url to be matched. Should the regexp itself
>   contain curly braces, they must be in matched pairs or escaped with a
>   backslash.